# "GetForegroundWindow: identifier not found" in visual studio 2015

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, c++-cx, getforegroundwindow

I am developing a windows app in visual studio 2015 using C++. I need `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetWindowText()` to return the app that is currently focusing on. However, it says `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetWindowText()` are undefined even I've included "windows.h". I tried go to the definition of `GetForegroundWindow()`, it led me to "WinUser.h", so I included "WinUser.h" as well. But it still could not help. Here are my code:

```
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <winapifamily.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace App1;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

HWND currenthwnd, hwnd = NULL;
char wnd_title[1024];

void App1::MainPage::Focus_app_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
currenthwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowText(hwnd, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
cout << wnd_title << endl;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are writing a WinRT app, not a desktop app.  You cannot use many of the legacy winapi functions, like GetForegroundWindow().  Nor are you permitted to interact with other processes like this, WinRT apps run in a sandbox that forbids this kind of interaction.  That keeps the kind of user that downloads an app from the Store happy.  High odds of course that you simply used the wrong project template to get started.

Comment: @HansPassant I see! I was using the universal windows app template. Is there any way I could detect the app that is currently focused using this template? Or should I create a win32/Windows Forms/WPF application instead?Thanks!!

Comment: I was not kidding.  Your app isn't even running anymore when another app gets the foreground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetForegroundWindow`and `GetWindowText` in the `WinUser.h` are declared inside `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` macro block. So you could use them only for windows desktop applications.

Comment: Thanks!! I just tried to add the declaration and the errors are gone. But it threw new errors in App.xaml.obj saying "LINK2019: unresolved external symbol public: __cedcl ..", which I haven't see before. Do you know what's happening? Sorry I'm new to visual studio and windows.

Comment: Of course it would. This API is unavailable for your target platform, so you simply could not use these methods. No way around it.

Comment: But my target platform is windows desktop as you said. If no way around, do you know any other methods I can use? Thanks!

Comment: Check your project preprocessor defines. See if `WINAPI_FAMILY` macro is defined.

Comment: Do not try and work around this by resetting the `PARTITION` for a UWP app. You can fix the compilation and linking errors with some trivial work-arounds, but your runtime behaviour will be undefined. You also won't be able to submit to the Windows Store (even if you don't want to go to the Store, you should not feel good about an app that uses unsupported "features" and can stop working at any point in time).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks!! Does it mean I create a win32/Windows Forms/WPF application instead of universal windows app?

Comment: Yes, if you have a requirement to use those APIs.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks!!